# Executor thread keeps running after hot deploy

Tags: java, jboss6.x

Is there any way to know when a war is being hot deployed so I can shutdown the old executor that is running scheduled tasks?  I'm using jboss 6 and I have a scheduled thread pool that is updating data periodically in the background.  When I hot deploy that thread pool is not shutdown and new starts up so I have multiple scheduled thread pools.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but it depends on where you start your `Executor` and which technology you use:

- in [ServletContextListener](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html): start `Executor` in `contextInitialized()` and shut it down in `contextDestroyed()`.
- in servlet, start `Executor` in `init()`, shut it down with `destroy()`
- in EJB/Spring bean: start in method annotated with `@PostConstruct`, shutdown in `@PreDestroy`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. It depends on how do you run this thread. If for example you are running it from sevlet use servlet's `destroy()` method to stop it. If you are using Spring use lifecicle of its Application context.